# Perl File::Tail with a symbolic link

Tags: perl, tail

BACKGROUND

I am using [File::Tail](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Tail) to tail a log file symbolic link.  The symbolic link gets updated after midnight to include a new date stamp, which unfortunately my script does not tail the new file after the symbolic link is updated.   Otherwise, my script works as intended.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Data::Dumper;
use charnames':full';
use Cwd 'abs_path';
use File::Tail;

my $symlink = sub {
my($log) = '/home/user/log'; 
};

my $file=File::Tail->new(
        name=>&$symlink,
        ignore_nonexistant=>1,
        tail=>0,
        interval=>0,
        maxinterval=>1,
        name_changes=>\&$symlink
        ) || warn $!;
print Dumper $file;

while (defined($_=$file->read)) {
# do a bunch of stuff;
}
```

QUESTION

How do I get perl to follow the updated symbolic link?

Comment: Looking at the Docs, I wonder if you've played around with the `resetafter` attribute?

Comment: resetafter => 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a return from the sub

```
my $symlink = sub {
my($log) = '/home/user/log'; 
return $log;
};
```

Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

From the File::Tail [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Tail#name_changes):

> name_changes
>
> Some logging systems change the name of the file they are writing to, sometimes to include a date, sometimes a sequence number,
>   sometimes other, even more bizarre changes.
>
> Instead of trying to implement various clever detection methods, File::Tail will call the code reference defined in name_changes. The
>   code reference should return the string which is the new name of the
>   file to try opening.
>
> Note that if the file does not exist, File::Tail will report a fatal error (unless ignore_nonexistant has also been specified).

So your code reference should return the name of the *new* file, which according to your question has a datestring in it. Perhaps something like this would work:

```
use Path::Tiny;  # file system agnostic path utilty
use Time::Piece; # data utilties

my $symlink = sub {
   my $time = localtime; # a Time::Piece object
   return path(
      '/home/user/log',
      join('', $time->year, $time->mon, $time->mday), 
   )->canonpath;
};
```

For today this sub would return: `/home/user/log20151112`

Comment: I've tried resolving the absolute path and tail the file directly instead of using the symbolic link.  my($log) = abs_path('/home/user/log');  which does not seem to work either.

Comment: Is that different than using Cwd to get resolve the symbolic link?